# Can I get a audio file without recording this audio?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I make a simple music web app by using Tonejs which is based on Web Audio API.

This simple web app can let you make your own simple music. It looks like this web app. https://musiclab.chromeexperiments.com/Song-Maker/

Each note related a sound sample AudioBuffer.You can arrange notes to make music.

It works well on web and I want to export the music as audio file(mp3 or wav).

I find that I can recoed the music and then export as audio file.

But I wonder if I can export audio file directly without recording? (It's annoying to wait recording)